# file upload encoding troubles with the file name. GWT

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-chrome, gwt, blobstore

I have a problem when I try to upload file in my gwt project (server on gae). I have FormUpload (com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FormPanel) end FileUpload (com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FileUpload) inside and of course server side. 
The problem is when I try uploads image with name which contains chart like "ó". But it is weird because when I manually change "ó" on "ó" it works (delete old ó and type from my keyboard new, the image I have is from another person send by mail).

On my formPanel I have:

```
setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
```

also I tray:

```
setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART+"; charset=UTF-8");
```

On server I have:

```
Map<String, List<BlobKey>> uploads = blobstoreService.getUploads(request);
```

and uploads size is 0.

Also I try deprecated method:

```
blobstoreService.getUploadedBlobs(request);
```

Also what is strange that I can upload the same image using Firefox but on Chrome, Safari and Opera I can't so maybe its browser error (bug).

Did anyone has a similar problem like me? I am struggling with that problem and I have no idea how to fix this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that you have to set the accepted charset of your form and the request charset.

So, in the view/composite where you are creating the formpanel, add:

```
FormElement.as(formPanel.getElement()).setAcceptCharset("UTF-8");
```

On the server side, when handling the request set the request:

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I don't have access to code and this file any more.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running that in dev_appserver and notice any error?

I also got similar error (not exactly happen on the file name, but on the form fields submitted along with the upload) and here's the issue https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9420&can=4&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log

I'm guessing there is something wrong on unicode handling on blobstore

Comment: Yes I tried (by eclipse plugin, GEP), but on local machine it's work fine. I use app engine SDK 1.7.4.

Comment: Also I don't think so that is wrong in: _unicode handling on blobstore_, because in firefox everything work fine and blobstor is server side part. But it possible that I am wrong.